# NetLogo: move turtles until they find the optimal location

Tags: netlogo, patch, turtle-graphics

I have NetLogo file and assigned for each patch a optimal value (the lower the value, the better). I would like to move my turtles until they all find a spot with the most optimal value. How can I implement this in a piece of code?
I already have this piece of code that prevents the turtles from directing to a patch that is not 'beach'. Still, their movements are randomly and I would now like them to move to a patch where the optimal value is the lowest possible.

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [
    ;ensures that next patch is a beach-patch
    ifelse [value] of patch-ahead 1 != "beach"
      [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; We see a patch that is not beach in front of us. Turn a random amount.
      [ fd 1 ]                  ;; Otherwise, it is safe to move forward.
      
  ]
```

Comment: have a look in the NetLogo dictionary for `uphill` and `downhill`, then come back if you can't make it work

Comment: Thank you! That works! However, the turtles are now also moving to patches that I wanted to exclude (see the piece of code provided in the question). I would like to combine this piece of code with the ' downhill ' code. How can I do that best?

Comment: you need to provide your code

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see your comment earlier. But now it works! Thank you